# Change Culture DateTimePicker For .Net Specially Persian Calendar

Tags: .net

. net datetimepicke can not Change to Persian calendar
I Need A Multi Culture DateTimePicker that support geregorian And Persian And Hijri Cultures.

Comment: Is it for web or for windows application?

Answer (score 4):

Check this out.
[CodeProject: Farsi Library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/FarsiLibrary.aspx?fid=287863&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=176)